# Install Linux From Live CD

Tags: shell-script, boot, system-installation, lfs

I have made a Linux From Scratch and built a live CD from it. I also wrote a script in `/usr/sbin` named `install-lfs`. When I want to install Linux, I just have to open a terminal in the live session and type `install-lfs`.

Now I want to be able to install it without booting the live CD i.e. i want to add an entry called `install` in isolinux menu, **which starts the scripts instead of bringing up the GUI.**

I have been advised to put the script in `/etc/init.d` but that would interfere with the live session too.

Is there any way I can pass special parameters from the isolinux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do pass the boot parameter `install` to the kernel and then have an init script which has a function such as the following:

`install() {
  grep -q install /proc/cmdline 
  if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    /usr/sbin/install-lfs
    reboot
  fi
}
install`

If it sees the boot parameter install then it will run the script and reboot the machine when it finishes. If it doesn't it will boot normally.

Comment: I have made the script. Now where do I put it? and how do I pass the parameter?

Comment: Put it in one of the early running init scripts.  The boot parameter should be added in the isolinux menu to this new option: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_parameters#Syslinux